# Should I use a comma or semicolon to separate these ideas?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas, semicolons

> - I can no longer remember her face, too
>     much time has passed.
> - I can no longer remember her face; too
>     much time has passed.

Comment: The second seems fine. Is there a specific query you have, or is it just the comma/semi-colon?

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'too much time _had_ passed?'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The first is a [comma splice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice). Both *I can no longer remember her face* and *too much time has passed* are independent clauses. They should be separated by a colon, semicolon or period, or linked by a conjunction. An excellent choice for this example is *for*:

> I can no longer remember her face, for too much time has passed.

The second example is grammatically correct, as both independent clauses are aptly separated by a semicolon:

> I can no longer remember her face; too much time has passed.

---

Here is the Strunk & White (Elements of Style) reference:

> **Do not join independent clauses by a comma.**
>
> If two or more clauses, grammatically complete and not joined by a conjunction, are to form a single compound sentence, the proper mark of punctuation is a semicolon.
>
> [Read more...](http://www.bartleby.com/141/strunk.html#5)